# Initializing data frame with columns from a list of names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of column names, such as

```
names = c("a","b")
```

I'd like to make an empty data frame with the column names taken from `names`, with 1 row where all values are `NA`.

```
"a"  "b"
NA    NA
```

I've tried something like this:

```
d = data.frame()
for(i in seq(1,length(names))) {
d[,toString(names[i])] = NA
}
```

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try `data.frame(setNames(rep(list(NA), length(names)), names))`

Comment: Works great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `replicate` NA by the `length` of `names` into a `list`, set the names of the `list` with `names` and convert to a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(setNames(rep(list(NA), length(names)), names))
```

---

Or another option is `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text=paste(rep(NA, length(names)), collapse=","), 
                   header=FALSE,col.names = names)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also do:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(NA, length(names)), nrow=1))
names(df) <- names
```

Comment: variation of a theme...`as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=length(names), dimnames = list(NULL, names)))`